# Combing data frame, rows not lining up properly

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to combine 2 data frames (`1960` and `2000`). These data frames are  different lengths but the column names are the same. My first attempt was to use the `plyr` package and bind based on the column names:

```
library(plyr)
combined <- rbind.fill(1960[c("Name","Gender","1960")],2000[c("Name","Gender","2000")])
```

This was fine but I noticed that it wasn't merging the rows properly. A sample of the data in the data frame shows that there are no females called Aaron born in 1960 on the first row but the 3rd row shows there are 20.

```
Name   Gender  1960  2000
Aaron  F       NA    35    29613
Aaron  M       NA    9548  2728
Aaron  F       20    NA    7511
Aaron  M       1772  NA
```

I then tried `smartbind` but got the same result:

```
library(gtools)
t <- smartbind(1960, 2000)
```

I'm not sure how to get female and male entries to correspond. I've also tried merging the data frames but I don't really like the output.

```
m <- merge(1960, 2000, by = c("Name"), all = TRUE)
m[is.na(m)] <- 0
```

If anyone could advise how I can get the rows to line up properly based on the name and gender I'd really appreciate.

EDIT: 
The two data frames consist of 3 columns: `Name`, `Gender` and `Total`. The `Total` column represents the number of people in the year with a particular name. The 1960 data frame shows the total per name for that year, and the 2000 data frame shows the total for that year. When I merge the 2 data frames the output is:

```
Name   Gender.x  1960  Gender.y  2000  
Aaron  F         20    F         35 
Aaron  F         20    M         9548 
Aaron  M         1772  F         35 
Aaron  M         1772  M         9548
```

What I don't like about merging them is that the M and F genders are showing on the same line. I can manipulate them in the data frame output so they line up but I'd rather produce it properly with code if you know what I mean?

Comment: Can you give us examples of the 1960 and 2000 data frames? And what, exactly, is your expected output? If the goal is to have a data frame with separate columns for 1960 and 2000 name counts, then `merge` is the way to go. What about the result do you not like?

Comment: The problem here seems to be that you don't have a unique identifier for the observations by which you can merge. If you only merge by name and multiple people have the same name the merge command cannot know who is the same person. You could try to create a unique identifier by combining multiple columns with the `paste0` command.

Comment: Thanks jdobres, Daniel Winkler and Scarabee for your help. I'm just starting out with R and still trying to get my head around it. I've edited my original post with more information. I'll try the unique identifier route and see how that works out. Thank you!

Comment: The command would look something like `yob1960$id<-paste0(yob1960$Name, yob1960$Gender) `  and the same for yob2000. This creates a new column with the name and gender as one string thereby you can match people by this column based on name and gender.

Comment: Or try  `m <- merge(yob1960, yob2000, by = c("Name", "Gender" ), all = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks @DanielWinkler - I went with updated merge in the end and it worked perfectly! I guess I was overthinking it before :) Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude the question and for future reference :

`m <- merge(yob1960, yob2000, by = c("Name", "Gender" ), all = TRUE)`

This will keep name and gender combinations in the same row for both years.